# Pointer / function argument issue?

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings

I'm making a little program that will use a stack implemented with a dynamic array to check if a phrase has balanced parenthesis and brackets. So far, I've just tried passing a phrase to the isBalanced function and just try and print out each char one by one. When the program gets to:

```
printf("%s\n", nextChar(s));
```

I get a segmentation fault and a warning about passing type char and expecting type int.Any help is much appreciated.

```
char nextChar(char* s)
 {
        static int i = -1;
        char c;
        ++i;
        c = *(s+i);
        if ( c == '\0' )
            return '\0';
        else
            return c;
}

int isBalanced(char* s)
{
        while(nextChar(s) != 0){
             printf("%s\n", nextChar(s)); 
        }
        return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
        char* s=argv[1];
        int res;
        res = isBalanced(s);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You ***really really really*** need to read the manual of `printf()` before trying to use it. The error is obvious.

Comment: nextChar(s) return char, not char*. %s need char*.

Comment: printf("%c\n", nextChar(s)); this will work

Comment: ok that was embarassing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`printf` expects `char *`, however, this code

```
printf("%s", nextChar(s));
```

gives `char`, because `nextChar(s)` returns `char` (Where you must get warning, if you use good compiler).

So, change this to,

```
printf("%c\n", nextChar(s));
```

Also, you're calling `nextChar(s)` twice, losing the value of the first call.
This should do what you are expecting:

```
int isBalanced(char* s)
{
        char ch;
        while((ch = nextChar(s)) != 0){
             printf("%c\n", ch); 
        }
        return 0;
}
```